# How to call use Batch File to copy a file to another location using vb 6.0

Tags: batch-file, vb6

I try to make a batch file and run in VisualBasic 6.0. The batch file is for copying or deleting or renaming a file. The file name is variable, generated by the application.

My following code is like this:

```
Dim STRFiLE As String

Private Sub callBatch(trans As String)
Dim StrBatch As String

StrBatch = App.Path & "\test.bat " & trans
 MsgBox StrBatch
Shell (StrBatch)
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
callBatch STRFiLE
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
STRFiLE = App.Path & "\test\LAT.TXT"
End Sub
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Since VB code is pasted, it appears it is where you are stuck. You have hard-coded the file name so whats wrong with it ? Do you want to pass it as a commandline argument for your exe ?

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Why use a batch file?

Comment: VB6 can copy/move/rename all by itself ...

Comment: Why do you need a batch file to copy a file from VB6, when it's perfectly simple to just copy the file in VB code? (And VB6 <> VBA <> VB.Net - they're totally different languages. Please use only tags that are actually applicable to your question instead of just randomly adding those that sound familiar. Tags have meaning and relevance here. If you don't know which of the three languages you're coding in, you have much more serious issues than shelling out to a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to wrap your parameters in double quotes - and maybe even your program name, since you're including App.Path in the arguments as well as the program path.

Sometime it can get mixed up with spaces in path. More likely when your batch file tries to read in your parameter - it will stop at the first space in the filename parameter.

**Try wrapping everything in double quotes** (note you need to escape them by doubling up):

```
Dim STRFiLE As String

Private Sub callBatch(trans As String)
   Dim StrBatch As String

   StrBatch = """" & App.Path & "\test.bat"" " & """" & trans & """"
   MsgBox StrBatch
   Shell (StrBatch)
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   callBatch STRFiLE
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
   STRFiLE = App.Path & "\test\LAT.TXT"
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding the additional quotation marks is the correct way - +1 to dbmitch

Comment: Appreciate the comment @AndreOosthuizen - not sure why someone thought my answer was not useful... but it's happened before. Sometimes makes you hesitant to suggest anything